# Stubbing push notifications with sinon

Tags: node.js, sinon

I would like to test a function that sends a push notification. I would like to stub the notification send. I use mocha and sinon. I tried to stub with several syntax, but it's not working. One stub I tried:

```
var sender = sinon.createStubInstance(gcm.Sender);
var gcmReturn = {
    multicast_id: 1,
    success: 1,
    failure: 1,
    canonical_ids: 1,
    results: [{
        registration_id: 'xxxx',
        message_id: 'yyy'
    }, {
        error: 'InvalidRegistration'
    }]
}
sender.send = function() {
    return gcmReturn;
}
```

The code to test:

```
var gcm = require('node-gcm');

// Function to test
NotificationService.prototype.sendSpecificNotification = function (data) {
    var self = this;
    // Process data to create the users, title and text parameters
    return self.send(users, title, text)
        .then(function(pushResults) {
            // expect ...
        })
};

NotificationService.prototype.send = function (users, title, text) {
    var registrationIds = [];
    users.forEach(function (user) {
        var push = user.preferences != null ? user.preferences.push : false;
        if (push) {
            var regId = user.preferences.pushRegId;
            registrationIds.push(regId);
        }
    });
    var deferred = Q.defer();
    if (registrationIds.length > 0) {
        var message = new gcm.Message();
        message.addData('message', text);
        message.addData('title', title);
        message.delayWhileIdle = false;
        message.timeToLive = 24 * 60 * 60;
        var currentDate = new Date();
        var notId = currentDate.getHours() * 60 * 60 + currentDate.getMinutes() * 60 + currentDate.getSeconds();
        message.addData('notId', notId);
        var sender = new gcm.Sender(config.gcm.senderId);
        // I want to stub that call
        sender.send(message, registrationIds, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                deferred.reject(new Error(error));
            } else {
                deferred.resolve(result);
            }
        });
    } else {
        deferred.resolve('');
    }
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

**EDIT**: The test

```
it('Subscription Push', function () {
    var sender = sinon.createStubInstance(gcm.Sender);
    var gcmReturn = {
        multicast_id: 1,
        success: 1,
        failure: 1,
        canonical_ids: 1,
        results: [{
            registration_id: 'xxxx',
            message_id: 'yyy'
        }, {
            error: 'InvalidRegistration'
        }]
    }
    sender.send.returns(Q.resolve(gcmReturn));
    return fixtureService.clearDatabase()
        .then(function () {
            return fixtureService.load('./test/subscription-push.json');
        })
        .then(function () {
            return notificationService.sendSpecificNotification();
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the sinon stub method? Example:

```
it('Subscription Push', function () {
    var sender = sinon.createStubInstance(gcm.Sender);
    var gcmReturn = {
        multicast_id: 1,
        success: 1,
        failure: 1,
        canonical_ids: 1,
        results: [{
            registration_id: 'xxxx',
            message_id: 'yyy'
        }, {
            error: 'InvalidRegistration'
        }]
    }
    sender.send.returns(Q.resolve(gcmReturn));
    return fixtureService.clearDatabase()
        .then(function () {
            return fixtureService.load('./test/subscription-push.json');
        })
        .then(function () {
            return notificationService.sendSpecificNotification();
        });
});
```

**UPDATE**

You aren't using the stubbed methods at all, there is no magic going on behind the scenes here that stub the method automatically on the notificationService. You need to use the sender you created or just stub the method out directly on the notificationService.

```
it('Subscription Push', function () {
    var sender = sinon.createStubInstance(gcm.Sender);
    var gcmReturn = {
        multicast_id: 1,
        success: 1,
        failure: 1,
        canonical_ids: 1,
        results: [{
            registration_id: 'xxxx',
            message_id: 'yyy'
        }, {
            error: 'InvalidRegistration'
        }]
    }
    sender.send.returns(Q.resolve(gcmReturn));
    return fixtureService.clearDatabase()
        .then(function () {
            return fixtureService.load('./test/subscription-push.json');
        })
        .then(function () {
            // Here you should be using sender.sendSpecificNotification();
            // Alternatively, you could simply stub out the method
            // on the notificationService directoy and avoid using the sender at all.
            // To stub out the method on the notificationService do this:
            // sinon.stub(notificationService, 'send', function() { return Q.resolve(gcmReturn); });
            return notificationService.sendSpecificNotification();
        });
});
```

Comment: I get `TypeError: Attempted to wrap send which is already wrapped`

Comment: Try to change that last line to sender.send.returns(gcmReturn);

Comment: I don't have the error anymore but the stub is not used in the `sendSpecificNotification` method. Basically the test time out.

Comment: Thats because the send method returns a promise, so you must wrap gcmReturn in a promise. sender.send.returns(Q.resolve(gcmReturn));

Comment: Same thing. When I log the value of `sender` in the `send` function, the `{}` is returned and not the stub.

Comment: Please add the entire test function to your example, testing with promises can be a bit tricky at first. Must make sure you are doing it right.

Comment: notificationService.sendSpecificNotification(); change to sender.sendSpecificNotification(); or stub out the send method on the notificationService directly with sinon.stub(notificationService, 'send', function () { return Q.resolve(gcmReturn); });

Comment: I updated my answer to show how to do the unit test correctly.

Comment: I ended up wrapping the call to `sender.send` into a new function in `NotificationService.prototype._gcmSend`. Then I stubbed `_gcmSend`.